# Display submenu on click on main menu which is an anchor tag with link

Tags: jquery, html

Hii I am trying to display sub menu on click of main menu. But the problem is the main menu is an anchor tag with link so when i click on the menu the sub menu appears but due to page load it sets to display none. I want to display the submenu after page load also. Please help me.

Here is my html code

```
<div class="SideBlockContent">
    <li class="Sidemenulist ">
<a href="http://kintu.goecommerce.com/categories.php?category=Kids">Kids</a>
<ul>
<li class="Sidemenulist ">
<a href="http://kintu.goecommerce.com/categories.php?category=Kids/Accessories">Accessories</a>

<li class="Sidemenulist LastChild">
<a href="http://kintu.goecommerce.com/categories.php?category=Kids/Accessories/Socks">Socks</a>

<li class="Sidemenulist ">
<a href="http://kintu.goecommerce.com/categories.php?category=Kids/Accessories/Socks/Boys">Boys</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Script code

```
$('.Sidemenulist a').click(function(){

            $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        });
```

Comment: It is asked already  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629092/how-to-prevent-reloading-of-a-page-after-clicking-on-a-hyperlink-but-redirect-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) for this

```
$('.Sidemenulist a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lcrv3w/29/)

**Edit:-**

```
$('.Sidemenulist a').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if($(this).next('ul').length>0)
 {
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
 }
 else
 {
    window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
 }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @MohitArora but i want the anchor tag to work also.

Comment: @Tuhin: it sounds like you want the same action (the click) to perform two different actions (loading the new page and opening the sub-menu). That seems counter-productive and more complicated than it should be, but on what basis should the JavaScript perform one action and not the other?

Comment: @MohitArora thanks for the updated code but i want the main anchor tag to work also

Comment: @David yes i want the same action (the click) to perform two different actions (loading the new page and opening the sub-menu)

Comment: And how should the appropriate action be determined? I will suggest that it seems to be a flawed user interface that has the same action, on the same element/control, doing different things.

Comment: @TuhinBiswas  but it will appear when page will reload or you can use cookie to save state of menu

Comment: @MohitArora hey can you give me a example how to do that with cookie becoause i tried using cookie but it's yet not working

Comment: @TuhinBiswas are you using jquery cookie plugin?